# SQL - How to compare data of a column while iterating row by row and insert new row if they don't match

Tags: sql-server

I have the below data in a SQL Server 2017 table:

```
POS_ID   Term Code        Status           IsActive
----------------------------------------------------
TR        101             In Progress        true
TR        102             In Progress        true
TR        103             In Progress        true
CA        151             In Progress        true
CA        152             In Progress        true
DA        161             In Progress        true
```

The requirement is I want to iterate each row and compare the current row `POS_ID` with the previous row and if there is a different `POS_ID` found then I want to insert 2 rows in between in such a way that the 1st inserted row's status for that previous `POS_ID` will be "In Progress" and true and 2nd inserted row's status will be discontinued and false and term code of both these 2 inserted rows will be Term code of new `POS_ID` of current row.

Something like in this example:

```
POS_ID   Term Code            Status           IsActive
---------------------------------------------------------
    TR        101             In Progress        true
    TR        102             In Progress        true
    TR        103             In Progress        true
    TR        151             In Progress        true   -- NEW ROW
    TR        151             discontinue        false   -- NEW ROW       
    CA        151             In Progress        true
    CA        152             In Progress        true
    CA        161             In Progress        true  -- NEW ROW
    CA        161             discontinue        false  -- NEW ROW
    DA        161             In Progress        true
```

I have tried using the Lead function to check the next value in the row for the column, but not sure how to do implement logic as mentioned above if values don't match insert 2 new rows

```
SELECT 
    POS_ID AS currentvalue,
    LEAD(POS_ID) OVER (ORDER BY uniqueid) AS NextValue
FROM 
    dbo.input_Main_data
```

Create table and insert script

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.input_Main_data
( 
     UniqueId bigint identity(1,1),
     POS_ID varchar(10),
     Term_code bigint,
     Status varchar(50),
     IsActive bit,

     CONSTRAINT PK_input_Main_data_UniqueId 
         PRIMARY KEY (UniqueId)
)
GO
    
INSERT INTO dbo.input_Main_data([POS_ID], [Term_code], [Status], [IsActive]) 
VALUES ('TR', 101, 'IN_PROGRESS', 1), ('TR', 102, 'IN_PROGRESS', 1), 
       ('TR', 103, 'IN_PROGRESS', 1), ('CA', 151, 'IN_PROGRESS', 1),
       ('CA', 152, 'IN_PROGRESS', 1), ('DA', 161, 'IN_PROGRESS', 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new rows to be inserted are based on the lag(pos_id) ordered by term_code.  Where the lag(pos_id)<>pos_id then insert 2x rows.

Using the sample data provided (as a temp table)

```
drop table if exists #input_Main_data;
go
Create table #input_Main_data
    ( UniqueId bigint identity(1,1),
    POS_ID varchar(10),
    Term_code bigint,
    Status varchar(50),
    IsActive bit,
    CONSTRAINT PK_input_Main_data_UniqueId PRIMARY KEY (UniqueId));
go
    
INSERT INTO #input_Main_data([POS_ID],[Term_code], [Status], [IsActive]) Values 
('TR',101,'IN_PROGRESS',1), ('TR',102,'IN_PROGRESS',1), ('TR',103,'IN_PROGRESS',1),
('CA',151,'IN_PROGRESS',1),('CA',152,'IN_PROGRESS',1),('DA',161,'IN_PROGRESS',1);
```

Insert statment

```
with lag_cte as (
     select *, lag(pos_id) over (order by term_code) lag_pos
     from #input_Main_data)
insert #input_Main_data
select lag_pos, term_code, [status], isactive
from lag_cte
where pos_id<>lag_pos
union all
select lag_pos, term_code, 'discontinue', 0
from lag_cte
where pos_id<>lag_pos;
```

Query (after INSERT statement)

```
select [POS_ID],[Term_code], [Status], [IsActive]
from #input_Main_data
order by pos_id desc, term_code, isactive desc;
```

Output

```
POS_ID  Term_code   Status      IsActive
TR      101         IN_PROGRESS 1
TR      102         IN_PROGRESS 1
TR      103         IN_PROGRESS 1
TR      151         IN_PROGRESS 1
TR      151         discontinue 0
DA      161         IN_PROGRESS 1
CA      151         IN_PROGRESS 1
CA      152         IN_PROGRESS 1
CA      161         IN_PROGRESS 1
CA      161         discontinue 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining the `lead()` and `lag()` functions with a common table expression (CTE), some `case` expressions and an `insert` statement should do it.

**Sample data**

```
create table MyData
(
  uniqueid bigint IDENTITY(1,1),
  POS_ID nvarchar(2),
  Term_Code int,
  Status nvarchar(15),
  IsActive bit
);

insert into MyData (POS_ID, Term_Code, Status, IsActive) values
('TR', 101, 'In Progress', 1),
('TR', 102, 'In Progress', 1),
('TR', 103, 'In Progress', 1),
('CA', 151, 'In Progress', 1),
('CA', 152, 'In Progress', 1),
('DA', 161, 'In Progress', 1);
```

**Solution**

```
with cte as
(
  select md.*,
         coalesce(lead(md.POS_ID) over(order by md.uniqueid), md.POS_ID) as prev_POS_ID,
         coalesce( lag(md.POS_ID) over(order by md.uniqueid), md.POS_ID) as next_POS_ID,
         coalesce(lead(md.Term_Code) over(order by md.uniqueid), md.Term_Code) as prev_Term_Code
  from MyData md
)
insert into MyData (POS_ID, Term_Code, Status, IsActive)
select c.next_POS_ID as POS_ID,
       case when c.POS_ID <> c.prev_POS_ID then c.prev_Term_Code else c.Term_Code end as Term_Code,
       case when c.POS_ID <> c.prev_POS_ID then c.Status else 'discontinue' end as Status,
       case when c.POS_ID <> c.prev_POS_ID then c.IsActive else 0 end as IsActive
from cte c
where c.POS_ID <> c.prev_POS_ID
   or c.POS_ID <> c.next_POS_ID;
```

**Result**

```
POS_ID Term_Code Status      IsActive
------ --------- ----------- --------
TR     101       In Progress True
TR     102       In Progress True
TR     103       In Progress True
TR     151       In Progress True
TR     151       discontinue False
CA     151       In Progress True
CA     152       In Progress True
CA     161       In Progress True
CA     161       discontinue False
DA     161       In Progress True
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b599348023227f31f0ee807b49346884) with intermediate CTE results and step by step construction.

Comment: Thanks @Sander it's giving output, but the sequence of data is not as per expected output not even matching with Result which you have shared, so the newly inserted row of TR i.e. discontinue is not coming after TR its basically not sorting data correctly I guess.

Comment: I added a "fancy" sort at the end of my fiddle to get the data in the same order as your expected result for easy validation of the result. What happens, is that the new rows get new, automatic `uniqueid` values. Not providing any sort will most likely return the data according to the `uniqueid` field (new rows end up at the end). Messing with the `IDENTIY(1,1)` column values is a whole other issue! One that deserves another StackOverflow question...

Comment: Got it thanks. But what if my values in the POS_ID column is not just limited to 3 values (TR,CA,DA)  let's say in actual data there will be many more such values in such scenario below wont work right ? 

Order by  case md.POS_ID
           when 'TR' then 1
           when 'CA' then 2
           when 'DA' then 3
end

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c493f79eac0a7af93b5094a52e5c85bb&hide=14) for a sorting solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help :

```
SELECT [POS_ID],[Term Code],[Status],IsActive,[Priority] from(
    select [UniqueId]
          ,[POS_ID]
          ,[Term Code]
          ,c.[Status]
          ,IsActive
          ,Last_Pos_ID
          ,c.[Priority]
          from(
                Select * from(
                SELECT [UniqueId]
                      ,[POS_ID]
                      ,[Term Code]
                      ,[Status]
                      ,IsActive
                      ,LAG([POS_ID],1) over(order by [UniqueId]) Last_Pos_ID
                  FROM dbo.input_Main_data) tmp
                  where Last_Pos_ID is not null and Last_Pos_ID <>[POS_ID] )b
              cross apply 
              (
              select 'In Progress' [Status],0 [Priority]
              union 
              select 'discontinue' [Status],1 [Priority]
              ) c
  
      ) d
  order by [UniqueId],[Priority]
```

This script jus generate new rows if you want you can union it by your data

the result is some think like this

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @SteveC and @Sander I used a combination of queries that were shared by both of you to generate the final result.

Sharing the final query here, so it might be useful for anyone with a similar requirement in the future.

```
;with lag_cte as (
     select *, lag(pos_id) over (order by term_code) lag_pos
     from dbo.input_Main_data)
insert dbo.input_Main_data
select lag_pos, term_code, [status], isactive
from lag_cte
where pos_id<>lag_pos
union all
select lag_pos, term_code, 'discontinue', 0
from lag_cte
where pos_id<>lag_pos;


-- to print
;with cte_sort as
(
  select md.POS_ID,
         min(md.uniqueid) as sort_num
  from dbo.input_Main_data md
  group by md.POS_ID
)
select md.POS_ID,
       md.Term_Code,
       md.Status,
       md.IsActive
from dbo.input_Main_data md
join cte_sort s
  on s.POS_ID = md.POS_ID
order by s.sort_num,
         md.Term_Code,
         md.IsActive desc;
```